# Flutter d_chart : How to combine two or more duplicated domains as one in the chart?

Tags: flutter, dart, graph

Has anyone known of chart before, I'm using d_chart.dart?

If there are duplicated domains, how do I add and combine them as one?

My expected output is 2021: 10 from 2021: 4 and 2021: 6

```dart
DChartBar(
    data: [
        {
            'id': 'Bar',
            'data': [
                {'domain': '2020', 'measure': 3},
                {'domain': '2021', 'measure': 4},
                {'domain': '2021', 'measure': 6},
                {'domain': '2023', 'measure': 0.3},
            ],
        },
    ],
    domainLabelPaddingToAxisLine: 16,
    axisLineTick: 2,
    axisLinePointTick: 2,
    axisLinePointWidth: 10,
    axisLineColor: Colors.green,
    measureLabelPaddingToAxisLine: 16,
    barColor: (barData, index, id) => Colors.green,
    showBarValue: true,
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can separate data to new variable, then edit it. you can check this code in [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?)

```
List realData = [
  {
    'id': 'Bar',
    'data': [
      {'domain': '2020', 'measure': 3},
      {'domain': '2021', 'measure': 4},
      {'domain': '2021', 'measure': 6},
      {'domain': '2023', 'measure': 0.3},
    ],
  },
];

// cek console
print('--------------');
realData[0]['data'].forEach((e){
  print(e['domain'] + ' : '+e['measure'].toString());
});

// start proses...
List newData = [];
for (var item in realData[0]['data']){
  int existIndex = newData.indexWhere((e) => e['domain'] == item['domain']);
  if(existIndex == -1) {
    // not found / new domain
    newData.add(item);
  }else{
    // update measure
    newData[existIndex]['measure'] += item['measure'];
  }    
}

realData[0]['data'] = newData;
// end proses...

// cek console
print('--------------');
realData[0]['data'].forEach((e){
  print(e['domain'] + ' : '+e['measure'].toString());
});
```

Console output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYI9V.png)

and finally set to widget chart:

```
DChartBar(
    data: realData,
    domainLabelPaddingToAxisLine: 16,
    axisLineTick: 2,
    axisLinePointTick: 2,
    axisLinePointWidth: 10,
    axisLineColor: Colors.green,
    measureLabelPaddingToAxisLine: 16,
    barColor: (barData, index, id) => Colors.green,
    showBarValue: true,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to preprocess your data.

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
    {
      'id': 'Bar',
      'data': [
        {'domain': '2020', 'measure': 3},
        {'domain': '2021', 'measure': 4},
        {'domain': '2021', 'measure': 6},
        {'domain': '2023', 'measure': 0.3},
      ],
    },
  ];

  // Combine duplicate domains.
  data.forEach((element) {
    element['data'].forEach((bar) {
      if (element['data'].where((b) => b['domain'] == bar['domain']).length > 1) {
        bar['measure'] += element['data'].where((b) => b['domain'] == bar['domain']).map((b) => b['measure']).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
      }
    });
  });
```

And later use the data

```
 DChartBar(
    data: data,
    domainLabelPaddingToAxisLine: 16,
    axisLineTick: 2,
    axisLinePointTick: 2,
    axisLinePointWidth: 10,
    axisLineColor: Colors.green,
    measureLabelPaddingToAxisLine: 16,
    barColor: (barData, index, id) => Colors.green,
    showBarValue: true,
  );
```

Comment: I got the wrong output, the domain '2021' has gotten 26, which is a logic error.

Comment: Even if they are not duplicates, they are doubled.